# How to Make Sketches pixelated in p5js

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, p5.js, pixelate

I am making a canvas game and I wanted to know if there was any way to make my p5 sketches pixelated? I was wondering if there was anything easier than basically rewriting the p5js library.

I tried changing pixelDensity() to 0.1 and it caused the sketch to be blurry.
[what I see after changing pixelDensity to 0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qegw.png)